# Hadoop produces only one output from reducer

Tags: java, image-processing, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Although I do know that Hadoop is generally not used for Image Processing, as a proof of concept, I have been trying to implement image processing using Hadoop. 
In course of doing so, I have successfully implemented the Sobel edge detection algorithm to use the MapReduce model and run under Hadoop.

My program is supposed to take a folder from HDFS as input and process the files in the folder and write the output to the HDFS. However, it is considering a single file from the input folder and writing a single file as output.

Here is the source code of the files https://gist.github.com/ardahal/f0046e50e04fadc28a96

Comment: Do you want multiple inout and output?

Comment: Yes, the reducer should produce multiple output if multiple input files were there in the input directory.

Comment: I do not see your mapper writing any key and values?

Comment: @Rags Am I doing it wrong ? If so please guide me. I will be thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be semi-automatic but better than nothing. 
Let say, your input directory is: `/user/hadoop/inpur_dir/input_i.txt`

```
Path pth = "/user/hadoop/inpur_dir/input_"

for(int i = 0; i < number_of_image; i++){
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, pth.suffix(i+".txt") );
}
```

and

Here is [multiple output](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html). This is better than what I proposed before